# Exclude a s3 bucket form the AWS config auto remediation action

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-config

Is there any way to exclude a s3 bucket from auto remediation action.

I have some buckets which should have the public read access. When you create a config(s3 bucket public read prohibited)rule and auto remediation action, action is removing all the buckets public read access, so i need to exclude some buckets from the action.

Comment: Why not fix the buckets?

Comment: Those buckets should have the Public read access.

Answer (score 0):

Check again on the AWS console. That feature has been added by AWS recently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).